# names of DESeq2 change after error with vegan adonis

Tags: r, vegan, contrast

I've had this issue with the naming (contrast) of the deseq2 output, where the naming out the output was not reproducible. Normally the comparison would look like: variable_level2_vs_level1 ("treat_b_vs_a")
But sometimes it would return as variable1 ("treat1"). Ive seen posts of this issue on other sites as well but I never found a decent solution (nor the cause).

Up untill now, it has been a very elusive issue, for I was not able to reproduce it easily.
But today I managed to figure it out and have come up with a minimal reproducible code that results in the issue below.

The problem only occurs if I run a bad vegan adonis model with incorrect contrast.
Maybe someone can help me better understand the root of the issue

```
library(vegan)
library(DESeq2)

mat <- matrix(sample(1:1000), ncol=10)
var$treat <- c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5))
var$y <- c(rep("a",10))

dds <- DESeq2::DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(mat, colData = var, design = ~ treat)
dds = DESeq(dds, test="Wald", fitType="parametric")
resultsNames(dds)
```

which gives treat_b_vs_a, but if I run it again after the adonis model:

```
adonis(mat~var$y)

dds <- DESeq2::DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(mat, colData = var, design = ~ treat)
dds = DESeq(dds, test="Wald", fitType="parametric")
resultsNames(dds)
```

I get treat1.

So somehow triggering an error with the contrast in adonis results in incorrect handling of the contrast by DESeq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you left out one important piece of information: in your example, `adonis` fails:

```
> adonis(mat ~ da$y)
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Your `y` was constant (had only one value) and could not be used. It is true that in **vegan** 2.5-x we do set contrasts (that's a user option), but we reset them later. However, if `adonis` fails because of invalid input, this resetting does not happen.

This could be fixed so that we reset the contrasts even in failures, but the future releases do not set contrasts and therefore I have no plans to fix just this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had a workaround by not running the failed adonis. But I was curious about the issue underneath.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the option for contrast is changed when you run the adonis function. You can see this [post](http://faculty.nps.edu/sebuttre/home/r/contrasts.html) for information about contrast. Below is to reproduce your error, first we store the default options on a fresh setting:

```
library(DESeq2)
library(vegan)
default_options = options()

mat <- matrix(sample(1:1000), ncol=10)
da = data.frame(treat = c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5)),
                y= c(rep("a",10)))

dds <- DESeq2::DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(mat, colData = da, design = ~ treat)
dds = DESeq(dds, test="Wald", fitType="parametric")
```

The above gives you the results with names. We can see the environment options and default settings are the same,

```
options()$contrasts
        unordered           ordered 
"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly"

default_options$contrasts
        unordered           ordered 
"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly"
```

Now run `adonis` on an example dataset, everything is ok:

```
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
adonis(dune ~ dune.env$Management)

        unordered           ordered 
"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly"
```

Run your example, which throws an error:

```
adonis(mat~da$y)
options()$contrasts
[1] "contr.sum"  "contr.poly"
```

You can see that it is now changed. And running DESeq2 will give you the results you see. You need to change it back:

```
options(contrasts = c(unordered = "contr.treatment",ordered = "contr.poly"))

dds <- DESeq2::DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(mat, colData = da, design = ~ treat)
dds = DESeq(dds, test="Wald", fitType="parametric")

resultsNames(dds)
[1] "Intercept"    "treat_b_vs_a"
```